# Interaction between predictors alone or with predictors with confounders

Tags: regression, anova, interaction

I have a question, about the effect of two predictors (regressors of interests or main effects) on the mean outcome. I will fit a two-way ANOVA model (type = "III"), which one should I use:

***Model 1***:

```
Outcome ~ predictor1 + predictor2 + **predictor1:predictor2** + confounder1 + confounder2 + confounder3 + confounder4 + confounder5).
```

The first model (two way interaction between the two predictors only) gives me non- significant interaction, so I can remove it and interpret the results.

***Model 2:***

```
Outcome ~ predictor1 + predictor2 + predictor1:predictor2 + confounder1 + confounder2 + confounder3 + confounder4 + confounder5 + 
predictor1: confounder1 + predictor1: confounder2 + predictor1: confounder3 + predictor1: confounder4 + predictor1: confounder5 +
predictor2: confounder1 + predictor2: confounder2 + predictor2: confounder3 + predictor2: confounder4 + predictor2: confounder5).
```

The second model gives me too many significant interactions, and the p-values of the predictors will increase too much and it is impossible to interpret.

So, is it appropriate to use the first model (with only interactions between the predictors)?
Because I really want to go with the first model, and we haven’t been taught about any method to deal with many interactions like in the second model.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Please edit the question to say more about the data that you are trying to fit. Unless there's a large number of observations it might be hard to use the second model without overfitting. By some definitions what you are doing isn't technically ANOVA; it's OK just to call it a linear regression model even with categorical predictors. Also, please say something about the nature the outcome variable--for some types of outcomes you might need to use a generalized linear model--and why you want to use Type III ANOVA.

Comment: The outcome variable is continuous, and the two predictors are factor variables, and i have a sample size of nearly 300 observations. the other regressors (confounders) are mix between continuous and factor variables. So, can I go with the first model or the second one? Or should I build a model with fewer interactions?

Answer (score 1):

There certainly are ways to deal with multiple interactions like those in the second model--if there are enough observations to avoid overfitting. But I suspect that you don't have enough.

A rule of thumb to avoid overfitting with continuous outcomes is to limit yourself to about 1 coefficient estimate per 15 or so observations. Three hundred observations might then allow you to estimate on the order of 20 coefficients in a regression model.*

But those coefficients add up quickly if you have multi-level categorical predictors. Say that each of `predictor1` and `predictor2` has 3 levels. Then each has 2 associated regression coefficients, and their interaction term has 4: a total of 8 already. Plus your 5 "confounder" variables add at least 5 coefficients, more if some of them are categorical with more than 2 levels or if you fit continuous predictors flexibly, like with a regression spline (usually a good idea).

In that scenario, your interactions of each of `predictor1` and `predictor2` with each of the 5 confounders would involve at least an extra 20 coefficients to estimate (2 for each predictor:confounder interaction term).

My hunch is that Model 2 is substantially overfit and that the apparent "significance" of some of its interaction terms might be an artifact of overfitting.

Even though you found that the interaction term in Model 1 wasn't "statistically significant," it's good practice to keep it in the model anyway and work with the full model. An "insignificant" interaction based on a *p*-value might be of sufficient magnitude to have substantive interest.

Ideally, you should think about the potential importance of interactions in the original design and choice of the number of observations. Applying your understanding of the subject matter is typically a better strategy than just throwing in all possible interactions to see what happens.

In a very large study you might be able to handle all those interactions. Then, instead of focusing on all the individual regression coefficients, you would evaluate together all the terms involving each of the predictors.**

For general guidance on setting up and interpreting regression models, I recommend Frank Harrell's [Regression Modeling Strategies](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/). Chapters 2 and 4 are particularly relevant to this situation.

---

*What you describe might better be termed a multiple regression model rather than ANOVA. Some people restrict ANOVA to the context of categorical predictors of primary interest. Adjustment for other covariates might then be called ANCOVA. Those are all just forms of multiple regression, however. Why get hung up on terminology.

**You say that you want to use Type III ANOVA. It's not clear why. Some argue strongly against that. See the manual page for the `Anova()` function in the R [`car` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=car).